# NPM - Deprecate check in Package.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

Is there a way to directly check a package.jsob for deprecated dependencies instead of finding it out during `npm install`? I.e. Just check and dont install.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to make some *pre-npm-install* checking with [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) utility. Install it globally and it will give you some information like

```
$ npm-check
webpack       MISSING!  Not installed.
              MAJOR UP  Major update available. https://github.com/webpack/webpack
                                      npm install --save-dev webpack@3.5.6 to go from 2.7.0 to 3.5.6
```

Also you may try [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) utility. I guess it's more useful (and it works faster). It gives an information not only for major versions:

```
$ ncu -l verbose --packageFile package.json
webpack         ^2.6.1  →  ^3.5.6
express         ^4.14.0  →  ^4.15.4
```

I was able to use the second utility only with `--packageFile` option.

As you can see, it does not deal with npm deprecation explicitly, but may help in case you don't want to make `npm install`.

Comment: npm has this feature natively, via `npm outdated`. Also I don't think this is what the OP asked, since you can deprecate packages in the registry via [`npm deprecate` command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/deprecate)

Comment: @gustavohenke No, `npm outdated` works only after you setup all project dependencies via `npm install`

Comment: Doesn't work. Try `npm install @types/commander`, then run `npm-check`. It'll tell you everything is dandy, even though @types/commander is deprecated.